# Does this line set two vars or only one?

Tags: c

```
int i, nhashprime = nextprime(2 * hashprime) ;
```

Does this line equal

```
int i, nhashprime;
i = nextprime(2 * hashprime);
nhashprime = i;
```

or does it do something else?

Comment: only one: `i` is uninitialized. Or, they are global variables, it's initialized to 0.

Comment: you can use e.g. `a=b=3` to initialize both to `3`.

Comment: @Ahmet: That could only be an assignment, not an initialisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This initializes `nhashprime` and not `i`. The `int` part applies to both `i` and `nhashprime`, but the assignment only applies to `nhashprime`. The code is equivalent to

```
int i;
int nhashprime = nextprime(2 * hashprime);
```

It's generally not a good idea to combine multiple declarations into one, except in the simple case with simple types and no initialization:

```
int i, j, k;
```

Note in particular that pointer markers do not distribute to multiple identifiers either:

```
int *p, i;
```

should be avoided and is equivalent to

```
int *p;
int i;
```

Answer (score 6):

No.  Your code sets only `nhashprime`.  `i` will be uninitialized.

Answer (score 5):

```
int i, nhashprime = nextprime(2 * hashprime);
```

means

```
int i;
int nhashprime = nextprime(2 * hashprime);
```

Answer (score 1):

(Carl posted the right answer.  I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment only to retain formatting.)

```
int i, nhashprime = nextprime(2 * hashprime);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int i;
int nhashprime = nextprime(2 * hashprime);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one just set the `nhashprime` while leaving `i` undefined. Of course if `hashprime` is undefined (I don't see any precedent initialization) then probably also `nhashprime` will be undefined.